# Prevent android deep link from redirecting to playstore if app doesn't exist

Tags: android, web, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I am working on a website for a product which also has an android application. I want to redirect the user from mobile web browser to the android application when a particular task is performed. I use a deep link of the format as below -

intent://#Intent;package=<PACKAGE_NAME>;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;scheme=https;end

The issue is that this link is redirecting user to playstore if app is not installed. I wanted user to stay on the web browser if app is not installed. How can we achieve that?

As of now, i tried replacing the intent with https to produce link of the format as below -

https://#Intent;package=<PACKAGE_NAME>;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;scheme=https;end

But it only works if I add the supported links from the app info, which has to be done manually. I am not sure if the fix for this is to be done in android on is there a way to handle this from the website?

Answer (score 0):

how did you do the part where if the app is not installed it redirects them to the playstore?
I want to do this for my app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).